# Devise Omniauth Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I have set up Devise and Omniauth (:twitter) and now I am getting an error that states

```
ArgumentError at /users/sign_up
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

devise/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>

    <% if f.object.password_required?  %>
      <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
      <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

On line 3

I changed it to

```
<%= simple_form_for(User.new, as: user url: user_registration_path(user)) do |f| %>
```

^^ **now that worked**, *but* I know this shouldn't be done. So I am not sure what the issue is with the "resource attr" but its testing my will to not rage flip this table :) . Any insights would be great!

**CONTROLLER CODE AS REQUESTED**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def all
    @user = User.from_omniauth( request.env['omniauth.auth'] )
      if @user.persisted?
        flash.notice = "Signed in!"
        sign_in_and_redirect user
      else
        session['devise.user_attributes'] = @user.attributes
        redirect_to new_user_registration_path
      end
  end

  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

SO i re-went through a devise set up. There was never any generated controllers. they are handled by the devise gem. The issues are with this "resource" variable that i placed in bold above. For some reason, that is throwing an error.

Comment: Can you post controller code?

Comment: Sure. Posted.  thats for Omniauth though. I think i have narrowed it to be a devise issue. Again though. i am not all that sure.

Comment: As you are getting unexpected behaviour in sign up form so issue should be in registrations controller

Comment: I did a search. Cant find a controller for it. I can link my github repo. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/rjrobinson/Hot_Jobs)

Comment: Can't see any controller or views in your github repo. Did you override devises registration controller?

Comment: nope. Before i started setting up Omniauth, devise worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the user.rb file

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session['devise.user_attributes']
      new(session['devise.user_attributes'], without_protection: true) do | user |
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    if encrypted_password.blank?
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

there was a end in the wrong place : It works correctly now.